# How do I get rid of _notes folder that Dreamweaver creates every time I sync my site?

Tags: directory, dreamweaver

The title says it all.
Let me just say that I already went to Site > Manage Sites > Advanced Settings > Design Notes and unchecked Maintain Design Notes.

I've googled and that should do it, but... it's not working! Am I missing something?
I'm tired of deleting these useless (to me at least) _notes folders.

Thanks!

Comment: Found it! Had to disable Maintain Synchronization Information as well. More here: [link](http://www.webworkgarage.com/2014/01/how-to-make-dreamweaver-not-add-a-_notes-folder-in-the-various-directories-of-your-website/)

Answer (score 5):

> The `_notes` folders are created by Dreamweaver to maintain synchronization information and for Design Notes.
>
> Design Notes can be used to to keep track of extra information associated with your documents, such as comments on status of the document (e.g. "in draft" or "complete"). Design Notes can be also shared between users of the same site by checking the Enable Upload Design Notes For Sharing setting. Other than for sharing with other users, the _notes folders are only used by Dreamweaver in their local storage locations and do not need to be uploaded to your server.
>   Source: https://forums.adobe.com/docs/DOC-1671

1. You can go under `sites`: 
   [image]
2. `Site -> Manage Site`: 
   [image]

   Or:
   [image]
3. Select your `site` and hit the `Edit site` button: 
   [image]
4. Then go on `Advanced Settings -> Design Notes` and uncheck `Maintain Design Notes` 
   [image]
5. It will ask if you would like to delete them, then can hit `Yes` to get rid of all of that `_notes` folders at once and for good: 
   [image]